# There are four groups of 100. What are the chances of 25 from one single group being picked overall?

Tags: statistics

There are 400 people in total, each divided into four equal groups of 100. What are the chances that when randomly selected, 25 people from the same group are selected  in a row out of all 400?

Comment: You only need to count the number of groups of 25 people.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. Are only 25 people being selected overall (in which case, why do you say "in a row"?); OR are more than 25 people being selected overall (in which case, how many?)

Answer (score 0):

The answer may depend on whether you ask for at least $25$ people from one group or exactly $25$. If at least, the chances are $100\%$ due to Dirichlet's formula. If exactly, you need to pick $25$ people from one group and the rest from the others, so: $$\frac{{100 \choose 25} \cdot {300 \choose 75}}{{400 \choose 100}}$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you meant the question to be as follows: there are 400 people, divided into four groups of 100; if 25 people are randomly selected from all 400, what are the chances they all came from the same group?

If that is indeed what the question was meant to be, then the solution is fairly straightforward: the number of ways to choose 25 people out of 400 is clearly $\,\binom{400}{25};\,$ the number of ways to do so with all 25 belonging to the same group is $\,4\binom{100}{25},\,$ as there are 4 choices for which group the 25 could come from, and then 100 people from which to choose the 25.

Thus the probability would be

$$\frac{4\binom{100}{25}}{\binom{400}{25}}$$